# MSSQL nvarchar IF PROCEDURE exec with nvarchar input

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, nvarchar

I want know how to release IF with update and how to exec procedure with nvarchar input.
There are table Dictionary with 2 values ('Orig','Translated')
I need procedure that adds or replace "Trasnslated' depending on input. There must be 2 inputs, no more and no less. For example

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Translate_Orig (@Orig nvarchar(32),@Translated nvarchar(32))
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE Dictionary
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Dictionary WHERE Dictionary.Orig=@Orig)
SET Dictionary.Translated=@Translated
ELSE INSERT INTO Dictionary VALUES (@Orig, @Translated);
END
GO

SET @Orig = N'Orig'
SET @Translated  = N'traslated' 
EXEC Translate_Orig (@Orig,@Translated);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE Translate_Orig (@Orig nvarchar(32),@Translated nvarchar(32))
 AS
 BEGIN

      IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Dictionary WHERE Dictionary.Orig=@Orig)
      BEGIN
           UPDATE Dictionary
           SET Dictionary.Translated=@Translated
      END
      ELSE INSERT INTO Dictionary VALUES (@Orig, @Translated);
 END
 GO


 SET @Orig = N'Orig'
 SET @Translated  = N'traslated' 
 EXEC Translate_Orig (@Orig,@Translated);
```

Comment: Sorry but I can`t exec there Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near 'Orig'.

Comment: Incorrect syntax near '@Orig' still exists. 1 error. Thank you anyway. I can`t vote up because of my reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are just running the CREATE PROCEDURE through GO as a statement.

Answer (score 0):

There EXEC that works fine. No brackets.
And "SET Dictionary.Translated=@Translated WHERE Dictionary.Orig=@Orig"

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Translate_Orig (@Orig nvarchar(32),@Translated nvarchar(32))
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Dictionary WHERE Dictionary.Orig=@Orig)
BEGIN
UPDATE Dictionary
SET Dictionary.Translated=@Translated WHERE Dictionary.Orig=@Orig
END
ELSE INSERT INTO Dictionary VALUES (@Orig, @Translated);
END
GO

DECLARE @Orig nvarchar(32);
DECLARE @Translated nvarchar(32);
SET @Orig = N'Name'
SET @Translated = N'Name_Translated'

EXEC Translate_Orig @Orig,@Translated;
```